# Wireless redstone signal in Vanilla Minecraft with command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm looking for a method to give a wireless redstone signal to a bunch of command blocks under iron doors in order to open them on distance on sunrise.. I'm not asking you to help me with the daylihgt sensor part, I'm just looking for a command to give to, for example, command block "A" in order to, when powered, gives a wireless signal to the command blocks "B" "C" "D" "E" and so on..

Template:
[image: Template]

Comment: Have you tried `/setblock` and inverse gates?

Comment: Why not just use redstone?
The daylight sensor does not have to be above ground. It can be placed underground and used inverted.

Comment: This is my commandblock-less method: http://i.imgur.com/QiArJ0k.png
Maybe it could help someone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this wireless redstone setup (Our door is at -90 102 159):

Command block left: `/setblock -89 102 159 air`

Command block right: `/setblock -89 102 159 redstone_torch`

The pig is just an ordinary pig.

[image: Wireless Redstone setup]

You can easily use more command blocks for more doors.

Comment: I really appreciate your help playyip but, it would be such a great idea post an image in order to explain what you know! This is the method that I use to open a door in particular at e certain hour of the day (in my case the sunrise): http://i.imgur.com/QiArJ0k.png

Comment: Sure :) _... a burning tree... really?_

Comment: I totally changed it

Comment: lol I was testing the doFireTick gamerule of Vanilla 1.8

Comment: Yeah you gonna click that tick button by my answer.. :)

Comment: By the way this makes the door(s) close on sunset is that OK?

Comment: Your method is conceptually right! Thanks! What I want to suggest to the other readers is to make a 3x3 area around the block where we are going to put a redstone torch in order to correct the X or the Z in the coordinates if something goes wrong! Another tip that I want to give is to make the redstone 13 long from each side in order to give the redstone impulses at 12900 and 23050!

Answer (score 0):

Just use set block. For a button like effect hook repeaters up to the back and set the delay to max and connect them to another command block which will replace the redstone block/torch with air, thus only activating whatever what not for a second or so. For a lever like effect, just remove the repeaters.